# Add button and matplotlib to boxlayout

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, kivy

In kivy, I bring up a modalview, and in that modalview is a Boxlayout that will have 2 widgets. 1 widget can be anything, the other is a matplotlib plot - so I can see both at the same time.

I can't get modalview to work with matplotlib, when I run this it cancels the modalview and just shows the matplotlib - again, the entire modalview just doesn't appear, it's just the plot. I tried making another kivy widget with a limited size_hint, then adding the plot to that, then adding the widget to my main boxlayout but it was the same result

I've attached my kivy code and the code for the plot, the image is what I want the modalview to look like, where the right side is the plot

Lastly, I'm sure there's other ways to do what I want, like matplotlib has widgets that I might be able to use. But that seems like bad practice to suddenly shift from kivy which I've been using all this time that I bet can do this somehow

Any suggestions?

```
   mainview = ModalView(size_hint = (0.6, 0.7))
   box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal')   # cols not rows

   box.add_widget(Button(text = "place holder", size_hint_x = 0.3))
   box.add_widget(python_testing.make_plot())

   mainview.add_widget(box)
        
   mainview.open()
```

```
   # this is python_testing.make_plot() mentioned above
   # Prepare the data
   x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   ratings = [4,5,8,9,4,3,2,6,8,7]

   plt.figure(num='cde')
   plt.plot(x, ratings, label='cde')
   plt.legend()   # Add a legend
   plt.show()     # Show the plot
```

[image: What I want my modalview to look like but with the plot in the right side]

Comment: I found a different solution. I didn't find a solution that used matplotlib. See answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I found something that can integrate matplotlib with kivy but the documentation was mega bad, the solution I found is better though.

I discovered kivy garden (user made kivy packages), which has a package to make graphs in kivy. Attached is my new code, and a screenshot of my program

- kivy garden: https://github.com/kivy-garden
- kivy garden graph (there's 2, but 1 is depreciated in favor of this one): https://github.com/kivy-garden/graph
- kivy garden graph docs: https://kivy-garden.github.io/graph/flower.html

Code: user has pressed a button that triggers this method. It makes a modalview, which contains a boxlayout, which contains 2 widgets - 1 is a scrollable gridlayout made of labels and buttons, the other is the plot. The code for the plot is the 2nd snippet of code

```
    # pm: ticker = ticker clicked
    def modal_view(self, ticker, instance):
        mainview = ModalView(size_hint = (0.75, 0.75))
        box = BoxLayout(orientation = "horizontal")
        
        # make a scrollable gridlayout
        scroll = ScrollView(do_scroll_x = False, do_scroll_y = True, size_hint_x = 0.3)                           # a scroll view will contain the ticker gridlayout
        ticker_grid = GridLayout(rows = len(self.ticker_list), cols = 2, size_hint_y = None)   # holds tickers
        ticker_grid.bind(minimum_height = ticker_grid.setter("height"))                    # makes the gridlayout scrollabel via the scrollview
        
        # populate the scrollview / gridlayout
        for i in range(0, len(self.ticker_list)):
            ticker_grid.add_widget(Label(text = self.ticker_list[i // 2], height = 200, size_hint_x = 0.6))
            ticker_grid.add_widget(Button(text = "", size_hint_x = 0.4))

            # if ticker is selected, add button to cancel it
            if (self.ticker_list[i] == ticker):
                ticker_grid.children[i].text = 'X'
                ticker_grid.children[i].fbind("on_release", self.modalview_cancel_ticker, ticker_grid.children[i])

        # combine everything
        scroll.add_widget(ticker_grid)                
        box.add_widget(scroll)
        box.add_widget(python_testing.make_graph())
        mainview.add_widget(box)
        
        mainview.open()
```

```
def make_graph():
    # Prepare the data
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    ratings = [4,5,8,9,4,3,2,6,8,7]

    # make the graph
    graph = Graph(xlabel='Dates', ylabel='Ratings', x_ticks_minor = 1, x_ticks_major = 2,
                    y_ticks_minor = 1, y_ticks_major = 2, y_grid_label=True, x_grid_label=True,
                    padding=5, x_grid=True, y_grid=True, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10)

    plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
    plot.points = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(x, ratings)]

    graph.add_plot(plot)
    return graph
```

Note if you use this code: in make_graph(), displaying the data points is tricky. `plot.points = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(x, ratings)]` is the only way I could do it

[image]